# serialize complex json object using WebAPI controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I am new to angularjs and ASP.NET webapi. I am working on some requirement which my base tables are as below

```
CurriculumID    SubjectArea CourseNumber
------------    ----------- ------------
303     GHIJ        101
304     ABCD        102
305     MNPQ        103
306     WXYZ        104

lookupId    lookupValue
--------    -----------
1       Very Useful
2       Somewhat Useful
3       Not Useful
4       Not Applicable
5       Elsewhere
```

I have created two model classes (course and lookup) for these tables. How can i genarate JSon data as below in the backed using webapi Controller method `public HttpResponseMessage getData(...)`

I need the resultant JSON data like as below

```
    $scope.questions = [
    {
        "CurriculumID": "303", "SubjectArea": "GHIJ", "CourseNumber": "101", "answers": [
         { "lookupValue": "Very Useful","lookupId":"1" },
         { "lookupValue": "Somewhat Useful", "lookupId": "2" },
         { "lookupValue": "Not Useful", "lookupId": "3" },
         { "lookupValue": "Not Applicable", "lookupId": "4" },
         { "lookupValue": "Elsewhere", "lookupId": "5" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "CurriculumID": "304", "SubjectArea": "ABCD", "CourseNumber": "102", "answers": [
         { "lookupValue": "Very Useful","lookupId":"1" },
         { "lookupValue": "Somewhat Useful", "lookupId": "2" },
         { "lookupValue": "Not Useful", "lookupId": "3" },
         { "lookupValue": "Not Applicable", "lookupId": "4" },
         { "lookupValue": "Elsewhere", "lookupId": "5" }
        ]
    }
.
.
.
];
```

Please look into the this link for better understanding
 https://plnkr.co/edit/73oA3rsrre8gqYX9V25W?p=preview

So how can write the two methods getData(to generate JSon data). please can anyone help me to serialize this structure in ASP.NET

https://plnkr.co/edit/73oA3rsrre8gqYX9V25W?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have modeled your SQL tables with the following entities:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int CurriculumID { get; set; }

    public string SubjectArea { get; set; }

    public int CourseNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    [Key]
    public int LookupId { get; set; }

    public string LookupValue { get; set; }
}
```

the next step would be to define a view model that will represent the structure you want to serialize:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int CurriculumID { get; set; }

    public string SubjectArea { get; set; }

    public int CourseNumber { get; set; }

    public IList<RatingViewModel> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class RatingViewModel
{
    public int LookupId { get; set; }

    public string LookupValue { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller you could fetch the entities from your database and populate the view model from them:

```
public class QuestionsController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/questions")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            IList<Rating> ratings = db.Ratings.ToList();
            IList<Question> questions = db.Questions.ToList();
            IList<QuestionViewModel> result = questions.Select(q => new QuestionViewModel
            {
                CurriculumID = q.CurriculumID,
                SubjectArea = q.SubjectArea,
                CourseNumber = q.CourseNumber,
                Answers = ratings.Select(r => new RatingViewModel
                {
                    LookupId = r.LookupId,
                    LookupValue = r.LookupValue,
                }).ToList(),
            }).ToList();

            return this.Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I followed your procedure but i got an error like as below. 

Type '<>f__AnonymousType5`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`2[System.Int32,System.String]]]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported

Comment: `[Table("Course")]
    public class Course
    {
       [Key]
       public string CurriculumID { get; set; }
       public string SubjectArea { get; set; }
       public string CourseNumber { get; set; }
    }`

`[Table("sp.option_lookup_st_fdbk")]
    public class option_lookup_st_fdbk
    {
        [Key]
        public int lookupId { get; set; }

        public string LookupValue { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: and in the method

`IList<option_lookup_st_fdbk> rating = db.option_lookup_st_fdbk.ToList();
IList<Course> questions = db.Course.ToList();
 var result = questions.Select(q => new
 {
                    CurriculumID = q.CurriculumID,
                    SubjectArea = q.SubjectArea,
                    CourseNumber = q.CourseNumber,
                   answers = rating.Select(r => new
                    {
                        lookupId = r.lookupId,
                        LookupValue = r.LookupValue
                    }).ToList(),
         }).ToList();
return this.Ok(result);`

Comment: It looks like anonymous objects cannot be properly serialized in the Web API. This is a bad practice anyway. I have updated my answer to show how you could project your entities to a view model which can then be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it is working now. I would like to know what is wrong with the earlier code. Can you please explain if poosible

Comment: The earlier code used anonymous objects which cannot be serialized by the Web API. Introducing actual view models does the trick.